# How to get the max item based on a dependent value?

Tags: python, list, max

I have this array:

```
array = ["a\nb", "c", "d"]
```

I want to find out which array's element has more lines and how many. I want this ruby code in python:

```
array.map {|e| e.split("\n").size }.max #=> 2
```

This works, but I want to know if there's a better way:

```
bigger = 0
for e in array:
    e_lines = len(e.split('\n'))
    if e_lines > bigger:
        bigger = e_lines
```

Comment: Not sure about the Python but the Ruby could be: `array.map {|e| e.to_a.size }.max`

Comment: Please don't include a tag for language X if you're only interested in doing it for language Y.

Comment: Also, care with wording: the Ruby code snippet doest *not* "find out which array's element has more lines".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [54]: array = ["a\nb", "c", "d"]
In [56]: max(e.count("\n") for e in array)+1
Out[56]: 2
```

If you also want a (possibly non-unique) element with the maximum number of lines:

```
In [60]: max((e.count("\n")+1, e) for e in array)
Out[60]: (2, 'a\nb')
```

Comment: "I want to find out which array's element has more lines and how many". This is just "How many"

Comment: As a note, this works using a [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Comment: @JBernardo The OP also gives an example bit of Ruby which does exactly what this function does.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
max(array, key=lambda x: x.count('\n'))
```

And then just get the `.count('\n')` of the resulting object + 1 to also know how many

Comment: Note that this gives *the string* with the largest number of newlines. Usually this is what one wants, but OP's ruby snippet gives the number of newlines in that string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the *exact* functionality, it would be this:

```
>>> array = ["a\nb", "c", "d"]
>>> [len(l.split('\n')) for l in array]
[2, 1, 1]
>>> max(len(l.split('\n')) for l in array)
2
```

But [unutbu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14883436/298607) solution may be faster.