# Python - 2d list max based on certain part of inner list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

So I have a 2-dimensional list (as in a list of lists) and I'm trying to find the largets inner list based on their third element.

This is what I have so far, but it only returns `j[2]`, not the entire list `j` where `j[2]` is the biggest.

```
big = max([int(j[2]) for j in cur2])
```

What I want it to do is return the entire max list out of each of the lists inside of `cur2` dependent on the size of `int(j[2])`

Please don't refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883395/how-to-get-the-max-item-based-on-a-dependent-value) because I don't really understand how to apply that answer to my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
max( cur2, key=lambda x:int(x[2]))
```

Example:

```
>>> cur2=[range(4),range(4,8),range(2,6)]
>>> cur2
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> max( cur2, key=lambda x:int(x[2]))
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thank you! :D That solved it. also, if you could give me a link into a deeper description of the key parameter, that would be nice.

Comment: @EthanBrouwer when `key` is used then the comparison between the items of the iterable  is done on the basis of valued returned by the function used in key.